# Selenium Button Unclickable Python

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver

I'm attempting to click the next page button on this [site](https://rotogrinders.com/resultsdb/site/draftkings/date/2018-07-02/sport/mlb/slate/5b3aafe73870401e20652804/contest/5b3aafe83870401e20652b84). I've looked at multiple proposed solutions on Stack Overflow for similar issues, but none of them seem to work. This is my current code as of now:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
next_button = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "html/body/div/div/div/main/div[3]/div[2]/div/div[3]/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[3]/button[2]/i/svg")))
driver.execute_script("return arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", next_button)
next_button.click()
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Does the answer also need to work on the second page? Both the proposed solutions hard code a [2] to get the 3rd matching item which is the > you are looking for. But once I hit that and look for the >, it turns out to be the second such item on that page.

Comment: What are you trying to scrape. There could be a more efficient way to get that through the api.

Answer (score 1):

I have written this code to replicate your scenario and it is working fine. I have used the `xpath` which search for `svg` element with some `class name`. The problem with the website is, there are many duplicate elements present in it. Because of that might be your code is not working. Please try below code.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("start-maximized")

driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
driver.get('https://rotogrinders.com/resultsdb/site/draftkings/date/2018-07-02/sport/mlb/slate/'
           '5b3aafe73870401e20652804/contest/5b3aafe83870401e20652b84')

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 30)

# Find Next Button and Click
Next_Button = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(
    (By.XPATH, "(//*[local-name()='svg' and @data-icon='right'])[2]/ancestor::button")))
Next_Button.click()
```

Do let me know if you have any queries?

Answer (score 0):

You may try as follows:

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
next_button = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '(//*[@class="anticon anticon-right"])[2]')))
driver.execute_script("return arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", next_button)
next_button.click()
```